# define multi-dimensional object of a given volume

Tags: math, geometry, euclidean-distance

this question is in theoretical math perspective.
In the space S = [-1, 1]^d, given a volume V, can I always define object in S with exactly this volume? also - can I surround any x in S with an object of volume V?
I would answer yes on these 2 questions because I only need to find multiplication of d positive real numbers that would be lengths of lines, and I assume I can construct it around any x in S, but I just want to be sure, and get some nice explanation.

thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it *is in theoretical math perspective* and this is a site for practical programming matters.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, let's say n is ceil(log2(V)), so V is c 2^n with 0.5 < c <= 1,

then one possible solution is the c th part of an n dimensional cube,

so for 7 you take 7/8ths of a cube, for 9 you have 9/16ths of a hypercube, etc...

The only assumption here is that "Volume" should be interpreted as the nth-dimensional measure in n-dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right your space `S` has coordinates in range `<-1,+1>` which limits its  volumes to:

```
V = 2^3
HV = 2^d
```

where `V` is standard 3D volume and `HV` is `d`-dimensional hyper-volume that can fit into your space `S`. So you can construct objects with volumes and hypervolumes up to this limit.

So if you want to construct object with volumes V or HV then you can create axis aligned cube of size `a`:

```
a*a*a = V
a = V^(1/3)

a^d = HV
a = HV^(1/d)
```

if `a<=2` otherwise your `S` is too small ...